# UISpec4J tests clashes with other JUnit test cases

Tags: junit, junit4, runtime-error, uispec4j

I have a bunch of JUnit test cases.

Recently, to test the GUI in my application I used **UISpec4J** APIs.

When I run the GUI tests alone there will be no problem.

But when I add the GUI tests to the test suite with holds the previous JUnit test cases, it shows a lot of errors.

Some of them are **NoClassDefFoundError, UnsatisfiedLinkError** and so on.

Why this happens ?

The following is my stack trace.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.awt.motif.MToolkit.init(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at sun.awt.motif.MToolkit.init(Native Method)
at sun.awt.motif.MToolkit.<init>(MToolkit.java:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:3)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:859)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:826)
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:162)
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:181)
at com.Db.<clinit>(Db.java:95)
```

Another one,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.Db
at com.Db.junit.control.DbActionControllerTest.setUp(DbActionControllerTest.java:32)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? It's very hard to debug your problem with no information

Comment: I had found a solution for that. Since I use EclEmma I can merge coverage sessions by running the two tests independently and later merge their results. But actually there should be no clash, anyway there is an error somewhere.